# keep base package unmasked

Tags: r, package

Twice now I have encountered the problem of `base` functions being masked by other packages. is there a way of being able to load other packages in to library but not let them mask the `base` package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it's always possible to use packages without also attaching their namespaces to the search path. The attaching, not the loading, is what causes functions with the same name to clash with each other. That is, instead of

```
library(pkg)
pkgfunc(a, b, ...)
```

do

```
loadNamespace("pkg")
pkg::pkgfunc(a, b, ...)
```

where the `::` operator means to call the function that is exported from the given namespace. You might run into problems, but they should be few.

For programmers coming from other languages, this will be more familiar than the usual practice in R of calling `library()` every time you want to use a package. (I do find it a bit odd that, years after R made package namespaces mandatory to deal with this issue, people still load every package into the global environment.)

If you don't want to do this, then you can prefix the `base` function with `base::` instead. This is an explicit reference to a function in the base package, and so will ignore other functions with the same name.

```
base::sum(1:10)
base::list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Comment: Thank you for such a comrephensive answer. Why not just use prefixes every time after loading packages in instead of exporting from the name space (as it seems you have to use prefixes then anyway)?